# How to know if my object is alive in C++?

Tags: c++

Is there a way to know that my object is alive other than declaring a static private member in class and increment it in constructor, decrement it in destructor. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean "alive?" I think the answer to this is something like, "a caller knows if it's alive because the caller is controlling it". How can you *not* know if it's "alive"? For what purpose are you asking about this?

Comment: If your object has been destructed, no methods of the object should run at all. If methods are called after destruction, that's an error somewhere *else* in your program. Your object is either alive, or it doesn't exist.

Comment: Too bad "No." has not enough characters to be a proper answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do it non-intrusively to your class with STL using shared_ptr/weak_ptr.

```
stl::shared_ptr<YourClass> p = stl::make_shared(...); // holds a strong reference to your type
stl::weak_ptr<YourClass> wp(p);  

cout << wp.use_count(); // "1"

p.reset();

cout << wp.use_count(); // "0"
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to know if you have at least one instance of a class instantiated? A static counter is pretty much the best way. It's how *I* would do it anyway. :)

Comment: Sorry, I should have stated that i can not modify the constructor and destructor in any way.

Answer (score -1):

If the code in question lives inside a non-static method, then your object is "alive" by definition -- as long as you aren't doing something unorthodox like deleting it from inside a method.

If you *are* doing that (which isn't recommended unless you really know what you're doing), then make sure you `NULL` out the pointer immediately afterwards and always make sure to compare `this` against `NULL` to check whether your object is "alive".

Comment: Doesn't answer how you can check whether the object is alive if someone deletes it.

Comment: And your own answer is also incomplete and cannot work if you are unable to modify the original class -- but I didn't downvote it, since it's still useful for specific situations.

Comment: I believe he can specify the original class... otherwise the question wouldn't make sense.